# $a_n = S_{n-1}$, arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I have an arithmetic progression.
$$a = -27, -19, -11, ...$$
The question asks me to find a term in the progression where the term is equal to the sum of the terms behind him. Therefore:
I need to find $n$ for $$a_n = S_{n-1}$$

$$a_1 + d(n-1) = \frac{n-1}{2}(2a_1 + d(n-2)) $$
$$-27 -8(n-1) = \frac{n-1}{2}(-54 -8(n-2))$$
With this I don't get to neither answer that could be logic. What are my mistakes?

Comment: I do this manually and I get $37$.

Comment: @JohnDouma The answers of the exercise says $a_{10} = 45$

Comment: I believe you are right. I was off by one. Either way, there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$S_{n-1}=\frac{n-1}{2}\left(2a_1+(n-2)d\right).$$

---

Note that $d=\color{red}{+}8$.

$$a_n=S_{n-1}$$
$$a_1+d(n-1)=\frac{n-1}{2}(2a_1+d(n-2))$$
$$-27+8(n-1)=\frac{n-1}{2}(-54+8(n-2))$$
$$2(-27+8n-8)=(n-1)(-54+8n-16)$$
$$4n^2-47n+70=0$$
$$(4n-7)(n-10)=0$$
$$n=10$$

Comment: Correct but still doesn't get something. Even tried to check what I get for $n$ in _WolframAlpha_.

Comment: @PichiWuana: See what I added.